# Typescript. Declare module in npm packet doesnt work

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tiptap

I'm using the Vue.js + typescript. I have project "A" in which I use a private npm package "B" (it is a component library) in which I use another package - the 'tiptap' library. It doesn't have types by default, so I wrote my shims.d.ts file in project "A" where I declared the module 'tiptap'

```
declare module 'tiptap' { //... }
```

It works fine. But when I move this file to package B, TypScript does not see them and causes an error that there are no types. 
[Look on the folder of package B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIMXo.png)

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'tiptap'.
>   'C:/some_path/tiptap/dist/tiptap.common.js' implicitly has an 'any'
>   type.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have copies of the file `shims.d.ts` in both project "A" and "B"? And the problem is that when compiling "B" the type definitions for tiptap are not found?

A common problem is the location of the `.d.ts` file. It must be in a directory where TypeScript will look for source files. Check the `"include"` and `"exclude"` settings in your `tsconfig.json` if you have those options set, and make sure that `shims.d.ts` is in one of the included directories, and does not match any of the exclude patterns.

Comment: Now shims only in project B. And this is not working. 
What should i write in config of project A to help typesrcipt parse shims in project B?

Comment: I think the right way to solve this is probably to copy the type declaration file to project "A". Generally a package is not supposed to bundle type declarations for other packages. Another option is to structure "B" in such a way that it's public interface does not reference any types from tiptap. In that case "A" would not need the type declarations.

Comment: But it will not solve my problem. I want to declare types in package B, becouse it must be reuseable. And this types must be referenced, typescript must show errors if i use my components wrong.